# Inflow/Outflow Count in Stata

Tags: loops, stata

I have the following data

```
 id   pair_id   id_in     id_out       date
  1      1        2          3          1/1/2010
  2      1        2          3          1/2/2010
  3      1        3          2          1/3/2010
  4      1        3          2          1/5/2010
  5      1        3          2          1/7/2010
  6      2        2          1          1/2/2010
  7      3        1          3          1/5/2010
  8      2        1          2          1/7/2010
```

At any given row I want to know what the inflow/outflow differential is between the unique pair `id_in` and `id_out` from the `id_in` perspective

For example, for `id_in == 2` and `id_out == 3` it would look like the following (from `id_in == 2`s perspective)

```
 id   pair_id   id_in     id_out       date            inflow_outflow
  1     1         2          3          1/1/2010             1
  2     1         2          3          1/2/2010             2
  3     1         3          2          1/3/2010             1
  4     1         3          2          1/5/2010             0
  5     1         3          2          1/7/2010            -1
```

Explanation. `id_in == 2` as received first so they get `+1` then they received again so `+2`. Then they gave out so it gets reduced by `-1` bringing the total to that point to `1`, etc.

This is what I have tried

```
sort pair_id id_in date 
gen count = 0
qui forval i = 2/`=_N' { 
    local I = `i' - 1 
    count if id_in == id_out[`i'] in 1/`I' 
    replace count = r(N) in `i' 
}
```

Comment: This seems incomplete as you do not show the Stata code you tried and what problems it creates.

Comment: If you have no code, you only need to compute a difference and a running sum. See `help gen` and `help sum()`. I agree with @NickCox this is incomplete as it stands.

Comment: @RobertoFerrer Updated, I just knew it was pretty off

Comment: Evidently then this is as far as you got, but my personal rule of thumb here is increasingly that questions without code are off-topic and don't get answered by me. Otherwise anyone could post here that they need Stata code. I don't see that fits the focus on the forum on code problems faced by professional and enthusiast programmers.

Comment: @NickCox Updated, I just knew it was pretty off

Comment: I see. I will think about this then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't follow all the logic here and in particular presenting transactions from the point of view of one member seems quite arbitrary. But a broad impression from loosely similar problems is that you should not be thinking about loops here. It should suffice to use `by:` and cumulative sums. There is an attempt at some systematic discussion of how to handle dyads at http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=dm0043 but it is only a beginning.

Please note that presenting dates according to some display format is a small pain as they need to be reverse engineered. `dataex` from SSC can be used to create examples that are easy to copy and paste.

This code may suggest some technique:

```
clear 
input id   pair_id   id_in     id_out str8 sdate
  1      1        2          3          "1/1/2010"
  2      1        2          3          "1/2/2010"
  3      1        3          2          "1/3/2010"
  4      1        3          2          "1/5/2010"
  5      1        3          2          "1/7/2010"
  6      2        2          1          "1/2/2010"
  7      3        1          3          "1/5/2010"
  8      2        1          2          "1/7/2010" 
 end 
 gen date = daily(sdate, "MDY") 
 format date %td 
 assert id_in != id_out 
 gen pair1 = cond(id_in < id_out, id_in, id_out) 
 gen pair2 = cond(id_in < id_out, id_out, id_in) 
 bysort pair_id (date): gen sum1 = sum(id_in == pair1) - sum(id_out == pair1) 
 bysort pair_id (date): gen sum2 = sum(id_in == pair2) - sum(id_out == pair2) 

 list date id_* pair? sum?, sepby(pair_id) 

     +----------------------------------------------------------+
     |      date   id_in   id_out   pair1   pair2   sum1   sum2 |
     |----------------------------------------------------------|
  1. | 01jan2010       2        3       2       3      1     -1 |
  2. | 02jan2010       2        3       2       3      2     -2 |
  3. | 03jan2010       3        2       2       3      1     -1 |
  4. | 05jan2010       3        2       2       3      0      0 |
  5. | 07jan2010       3        2       2       3     -1      1 |
     |----------------------------------------------------------|
  6. | 02jan2010       2        1       1       2     -1      1 |
  7. | 07jan2010       1        2       1       2      0      0 |
     |----------------------------------------------------------|
  8. | 05jan2010       1        3       1       3      1     -1 |
     +----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

A specific pair (as defined by `pair_id`) is always conformed by two entities that can be ordered in one of two ways. For example, entity 5 with entity 8, and entity 8 with entity 5. If one is receiving, the other is giving out, *necessarily*.

Two slightly different ways of approaching the problem can be found below.

```
clear all
set more off

*----- example data -----

input id   pair_id   id_in     id_out str8 sdate
1      1        2          3          "1/1/2010"
2      1        2          3          "1/2/2010"
3      1        3          2          "1/3/2010"
4      1        3          2          "1/5/2010"
5      1        3          2          "1/7/2010"
6      2        2          1          "1/2/2010"
7      3        1          3          "1/5/2010"
8      2        1          2          "1/7/2010" 
end 
gen date = daily(sdate, "MDY") 
format date %td 
drop sdate

sort pair_id date id
list, sepby(pair_id)

*---- what you want -----

// approach 1
bysort pair_id (date id) : gen sum1 = sum(cond(id_in == id_in[1], 1, -1))
gen sum2 = -1 * sum1

// approach 2
bysort pair_id (id_in date id) : gen temp = cond(id_in == id_in[1], 1, -1)
bysort pair_id (date id) : gen sum100 = sum(temp)
gen sum200 = -1 * sum100

// list
drop temp
sort pair_id date
list, sepby(pair_id)
```

The first approach involves creating a variable that holds the differential for the entity that first receives according to the `date` variable. `sum1` does just that. Variable `sum2` holds the differential for the other entity.

The second approach creates a variable that holds the differential for the entity that has the smallest identifying number. I've named it `sum100`. Variable `sum200` holds the information for the other entity.

Note that I added `id` to the sorting list in case `pair_id date` does not uniquely identify observations.

The second approach is equivalent to the code provided by @NickCox, or so I believe.

The results:

```
. list, sepby(pair_id)

     +---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
     | id   pair_id   id_in   id_out        date   sum1   sum2   sum100   sum200 |
     |---------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |  1         1       2        3   01jan2010      1     -1        1       -1 |
  2. |  2         1       2        3   02jan2010      2     -2        2       -2 |
  3. |  3         1       3        2   03jan2010      1     -1        1       -1 |
  4. |  4         1       3        2   05jan2010      0      0        0        0 |
  5. |  5         1       3        2   07jan2010     -1      1       -1        1 |
     |---------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  6. |  6         2       2        1   02jan2010      1     -1       -1        1 |
  7. |  8         2       1        2   07jan2010      0      0        0        0 |
     |---------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  8. |  7         3       1        3   05jan2010      1     -1        1       -1 |
     +---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Check them carefully, as the difference between both approaches is subtle, at least initially.